# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP not sending (returning?) on one server, but does on all others

Tags: asp-classic, msxml

I have an asp classic page that uses MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP on Server 2008. It's been in production for over a decade.  The same code runs on an exact copy of the 2008 server, a 2012 Server, a 2019 server, and Windows 10 without issue.  This had to have changed recently as it's used almost daily and we just have reports of it today.

It doesn't give an error.  I just calls MediaServiceRequest.Send and never comes back. I've tried other ways to create the object but they all do the same thing.  The url is a web page on the same server as the caller.

```
Set MediaServiceRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
'Set MediaServiceRequest = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
'Set MediaServiceRequest = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
'Set MediaServiceRequest = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinMediaServiceRequest.5.1")
'Set MediaServiceRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
'Set MediaServiceRequest = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
f.writeline(now & " Error:" & Err.Number)  --> Is 0 here
MediaServiceRequest.Open "POST", url, false
f.writeline(now & " Error:" & Err.Number)  --> Is 0 here
MediaServiceRequest.Send s
f.writeline(now & " Error:" & Err.Number)  --> Never gets here
```

I've re-registered MSXML3 and 6 but no change.  Doesn't matter if it's http or https.  When I put the url and s content into a browser, it responds properly.  What else can I check?

EDIT: 8/6/19 8:17 am.  I just found that it will work as long as the url is NOT on the same server!  I tried another web site on the same server, same problem.  I tried one of my other web on another server and it works!  After reading a bit, one workaround was to set "Enable server-side debugging" to false in IIS but that's how it's set now.

It also appears that Microsoft doesn't recommend using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP on the same server.  What is the option then??

EDIT: 8/6/19 7:21 pm.  I've been trying to

```
'Set MediaServiceRequest = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Set MediaServiceRequest = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
'MediaServiceRequest.option(9) = 512 'and 128, 1024
MediaServiceRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check", false
MediaServiceRequest.Send 
f.writeline(now & " sentObject")
s = MediaServiceRequest.ResponseText
f.writeline(now & " howmyssl:" & s)
```

I've switched the different types of objects and options but I just can't get a response from howsmyssl.com.  I can't get WinHttp.WinHTTPRequest.5.1 to work as a replacement from the original issue.  I'm still getting the Schannel errors in the event log no matter what I do with WinHttp.WinHTTPRequest.5.1.  I just went to SSLlabs.com and we've gone from an A to a B!!  I'll have to see how that happened.

Comment: Rebooted and still no change.

Comment: Have you got On Error turned on or off? If you put an On Error Goto 0 before the code does it exit with any kind of error? What's the timeout on the script? Any recent  changes on the Server? What's the TLS version in use by default?

Comment: I didn't have an "on error" but I added the On Error Goto 0 and no change and no error.  Timeout is IIS default.  Default TLS is 1.2 but allows 1.1 and 1.0.  This server has a twin and the other one is ok.  No changes to this that's not made to that one... that we know of.  See Edit above for more info on recent findings.

Comment: Oh yes! I see https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/316451/info-do-not-send-serverxmlhttp-or-winhttp-requests-to-the-same-server so they recommend "If the ServerXMLHTTP or WinHTTP component must send a request to another ASP on the same server, the target ASP must be located in a different virtual directory and set to run in high isolation." so can you separate the code that requests from the code that accepts into different virtual directories then?

Comment: It can't even be different web sites on the same physical server!  I tried from one site to another on the same server and it won't work.  MS doesn't even suggest an alternative so don't know what best alternative is.

Comment: Zapier? You could set it up to send your data to Zapier, then that posts it back to your endpoint...

Comment: Ok, I was able to find an error!  "The following fatal alert was generated: 40. The internal error state is 813." listed under Schannel in the System event log.  Found it by accident because it says nothing about IIS or anything related.  Just a bunch of entries that looked like the same time as my testing.  I switched from https to http and it worked.  So, I'm guessing something to do with TLS?  Would still like this to work with https though!

Comment: Curious, if you do a Classic ASP GET via "WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1" to https://howsmyssl.com/a/check then it returns whatever TLS your request is using. Then you can compare it to your website https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/, just to check they are compatible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ralpharama was on the right track with TLS and SSLlabs.  When I checked the server with SSLlabs.com we were somehow back to a "B" rating.  We ran the IIS Crypto tool and reapplied the security template to get every setting back where it should be.  After rebooting, we had an "A" again and MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP was working again!